# How to run ionic cordova on Android device?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run my ionic app on an android device by running the following command:

`ionic cordova run andoid --device`

However, I get the following error message:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 41s
>
> 42 actionable tasks: 42 executed
>
> Built the following apk(s):
>
> C:\Users\myProfile\Desktop\ionic\Restrr\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
>
> native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk --device
>
> [native-run] Selected hardware device 2410169c6d0c7ece
>
> [native-run] Installing platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk...
>
> [native-run] ERR_UNKNOWN: Non-zero exit code from adb: 1 [ERROR] An
>
> error occurred while running subprocess native-run.
>
> native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-d... exited with
>   exit code 1.

When I search Programs & Features for 'Java', I get the following programs:

[image: picOne]

I also added a `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable below, but the same error message is appearing:

[image: picTwo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your java `jdk` then install

> https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed the `jdk`, & installed version 8. I've also updated my question above with the existing versions, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: do you installed android sdk ?

Comment: I have and android sdk folder in the path I mentioned above under ANDROID_SDK_ROOT. I uninstalled `JAVA(TM) SE Development Kit 10.0.2 (64-bit)` from above, & I am now getting a different error message. Will post the new error message above

Answer (score 0):

Running

> cordova clean

in terminal worked for me